# Se eu declarar um variável e não usá-la no corpo do programa, ele compilará?

Tags: c++, variáveis, memória

Tenho um programa e deixei uma variável declarada, porém não usei no corpo do programa.

Comment: Você tentou compilar este programa? Talvez isso já responda à sua própria pergunta :)

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 3):

Depende da configuração do compilador. É possível habilitar ou desabilitar isso. Tem um jeito bem simples de descobrir qual é o padrão do seu compilador, compile nessas condições e veja se compila. Eu aconselho manter isso ligado e não deixar uma variável declarada e sem uso, acaba esquecendo ela lá e vai desorganizando o código, se não usou, apague-a, se precisa mais pra frente crie novamente.

Note que a variável não será criada na aplicação. Pelo menos em C variáveis só são criadas se possuem utilização, a questão é só organização do código. Na verdade até variáveis utilizadas podem ser removidas depois de compiladas, variável é um conceito só existe em código. Se vai ocupar espaço na memória ou não é uma questão secundária a isso. Em muitos casos mesmo variáveis utilizadas desaparecem totalmente e tudo acaba sendo feito no registrador, não consumindo memória.

Para quem nunca viu não compilar por esse motivo é só [ver no **ideone** um código simples que não compila](https://ideone.com/WGEbJs).

Answer (score 1):

Nunca vi uma situação em que o programa não compile por esse motivo, mas isso não é suficiente para afirmar que sempre dará certo.

Caso compile e o compilador utilize uma técnica de otimização chamada DCE (*Dead Code Elimination*), a variável não fará parte do resultado final da compilação. Mais detalhes, com exemplo: http://compileroptimizations.com/category/dead_code_elimination.htm

Comment: É possivel de compilar e fazer com que todos os avisos sejam interpretados como erros, e nesse caso não iria de facto compilar. Mas isso não será o padrão é claro, é preciso que a pessoa tenha configurado dessa maneira previamente.

Answer (score 0):

Caso você queira manter apenas para lembrar vc pode marcar como momentário, assim não há nenhum risco de ficar ocupando memória desnecessária, apesar de como já citado pelos colegas acima, dependendo da configuração o compilador irá remover.